# BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write csv data from S3 to DynamoDB using AWS Lambda function. I am currently receiving the following error 'BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema'.

Is there a quick fix to this problem?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def csv_reader(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    rows = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')

    table = dynamodb.Table('customer_id')

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item={

                'Customer-ID':row.split(',')[0],
                'Name':row.split(',')[1]
            })
```

Error looks like this:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the
>   schema: ClientError Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 22, in csv_reader
>   'Name':row.split(',')[1]
>
> File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 156, in **exit**
>   self._flush()
>
> File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 137, in _flush
>   RequestItems={self._table_name: items_to_send})
>
> File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call return
>   self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>
> File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
>   raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>
> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the
>   schema

I would expect the data to write from the CSV file to the DynamoDB. Completely new to AWS & Python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it says `The provided key element does not match the schema`, you should provide the schema, and maybe some example input you're using

Comment: I received this error because I was passing data in a dynamodb format but this method expects pure values, i.e., it wants items in the form {'pk': 'abcd', 'sk': 'efgh'} as opposed to {'pk': {'S': 'abcd'}, 'sk': {'S': 'efgh'}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When putting an item you must provide all the mandatory fields, otherwise it will fail with the mentioned exception.

Double check your Table schema and check the mandatory values: at least a Hash Key is mandatory. If you have configured a Hash Key with a Range key, then you must provide both values. Without further information from your table it is difficult for us to guess, but I will try to summarise the problem in the next couple of lines. If it still does not suffice, please update your question with the Table Schema.

So let's say your HashKey is named `id`, your code should look like this:

```
batch.put_item(Item={
            'id': 'some-id'
            'Customer-ID':row.split(',')[0],
            'Name':row.split(',')[1]
        })
```

If a range key is also set and it's named, let's say, `test`, then your code should look like this:

```
batch.put_item(Item={
            'id': 'some-id',
            'test': 'some-value',
            'Customer-ID':row.split(',')[0],
            'Name':row.split(',')[1]
        })
```

If you're not sure how Hash and Range key work together, I suggest you read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this error because your CSV contains numbers. What you have to remember is that when you do `row.split(',')`, it splits the comma-separated values, and they are strings at this point. Thus, your primary key which you've probably declared as an int is getting a string value.

Do:

`'Customer-ID':int(row.split(',')[0])`

That should solve your problem.